# Do the R parallel extensions break the `apply` metaphor?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

Every time I see a question on parallel processing in R, it uses the `foreach` function.  Since `for` loops are not very R-like, is there a parallel version of `apply`, and if so why isn't it more popular?

Comment: In my case the appeal of `foreach` is that it lets me pass more than one variable into the function, choose how to assemble the results and is more readable than the `apply` equivalents. I don't know how they compare in terms of speed though.

Comment: @Backlin: But the same criticisms could be made of `for` vs. `apply` (the non-parallel versions), and people argue vociferously for the apply family.  It's as much a style thing as a speed thing....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are numerous parallel versions of `*apply`, starting with

- `parLapply()` in snow
- `mclapply()` in multicore
- `mpi.apply()` in Rmpi

as well as dedicated packages such as papply (possibly no longer maintained).

Comment: Are they just so easy to use that no one asks any questions about them then? :-)  Maybe it's just been the last few weeks but there have been quite a few foreach questions and none on these.  Searching for these three on SO yields results only for mclapply(), and then not so many.

Comment: You could start with a survey paper as eg [this one in JSS](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01/paper).

Comment: It is also referenced from the [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) which I assume you have seen?

Comment: I've seen the task view, and I think I may have glanced over the paper before but hadn't fully appreciated it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Dirk is correct.  I'd add that the `plyr` package now has support for a parallel backend.

In the case of the `plyr` package, it may be the case that little is mentioned because dropping in a parallel backend doesn't take any thought: it's just a flag.

Comment: I think you might be right that it doesn't get any mention because it just works.  Why doesn't it work the same way with apply?  Ultimately that seems like the right metaphor: let the libraries handle the parallelization and all the user has to do is decide whether they want it run parallel or not....

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, some of this functionality is fairly new and people are just beginning to adopt it.

Comment: Yes but foreach seems to be the newest of them and it's the one getting all the attention....